# play framework first project on NetBeans not working

Tags: java, netbeans, frameworks, playframework

I am creating my first project using play framework on NetBeans and I have done all the steps needed to create the project, nebeansify and so on. however the project is created with errors like package models doesn't exsit. so anyone knows if I am doing something wrong, also if anyone can give me useful links, videos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If it's complaining about the models package being empty, just add a
   model to it.
2. If that doesn't work, try closing the project, doing `play netbeansify` again and
   reopening the project in NetBeans.
3. If it still doesn't work you can always add the missing dependencies to
   the classpath manually (Project Properties -> Java Sources
   Classpath). But this might mean you did something wrong while installing Play.